# Can you make a variable in a list and then call it?

Tags: python

My friend and I are making a python RPG game and I’m currently working on weapons. I’ve set up a system that allows you to roll for damage and chance to hit like in dnd. I’m using a list to make the weapons and then using `print(exampleWeapon[0])` for the damage and changing the 0 to a  1 for the chance to hit. I’ve tried using a variable so I can print the damage output a lot easier with `print(handAxe[dmg])` but I can’t seem to make a variable in the list, is there a way to do this or do have to stick with how I was doing.
Here’s my script

````
handAxe = [
    random.randint(1,6),
    random.randint(1,20),
]


print(handAxe[0])

print(handAxe[1])```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionnary for this:

```py
handAxe = {"dmg": random.randint(1, 6), "hit": random.randint(1, 20)}
```

You would then access them by `handAxe["dmg"]` and `handAxe["hit"]` respectively.

However, this means that you would have to redefine this variable each time. Otherwise, even though the value for the damage would be determined randomly when you define `handAxe`, it would stay at the same value thereafter.

A cleaner way to do it may be to use Object Oriented Programming and in particular properties.

```py
class HandAxe:
    @property
    def damage(self):
        return random.randint(1, 6)
    
    @property
    def hit(self):
        return random.randint(1, 20)

weapon = HandAxe()
print(weapon.damage)  # Prints 2
print(weapon.damage)  # Prints 1
print(weapon.hit)  # Prints 13
```

An even cleaner way to do it may be to use [static properties](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/221740/python-decorator-to-support-static-properties), so that you won't have to instantiate the `HandAxe` class.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dictionaries`:

```
hand_axe = {'damage': random.randint(1, 6),
            'hit_chance': random.randint(1, 20)}
print(hand_axe['damage'], hand_axe['hit_chance'])
```

Or you could use `namedtuples`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

weapon = namedtuple('Weapon', ['damage', 'hit_chance'])
hand_axe = weapon(damage=random.randint(1, 6),
                  hit_chance=random.randint(1, 20))
print(hand_axe.damage, hand_axe.hit_chance)
```

Or you could write a simple `class` ...